# After setting up ssl I cannot access my site django&apache

Tags: django, apache, http, ssl, https

I created a demo for my domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) which only returns the index as you can see below.

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is a demo")
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",index),
]
```

I was able to access my site with domain name (I made the "A" dns record in godaddy site) and this was the `<VirtualHost *:80>`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName loopingaround.com
        ServerAlias www.loopingaround.com

        ErrorLog /django-pro/site/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /django-pro/site/logs/access.log combine

        alias /static /django-pro/site/public/static
        <Directory /django-pro/site/public/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        alias /media /django-pro/site/public/media
        <Directory /django-pro/site/public/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /django-pro/src/tutorial>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess tutorial python-home=/django-pro/venv python-path=/django-pro/src/
        WSGIProcessGroup tutorial
        WSGIScriptAlias / /django-pro/src/tutorial/wsgi.py



</VirtualHost>
```

then I used "ssl for free" for creating a ssl certificate for my site and set the files they provided.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName loopingaround.com
        ServerAlias www.loopingaround.com
        Redirect / https://loopingaround.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName loopingaround.com
        ServerAlias www.loopingaround.com

        ErrorLog /django-pro/site/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /django-pro/site/logs/access.log combine

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt

        alias /static /django-pro/site/public/static
        <Directory /django-pro/site/public/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        alias /media /django-pro/site/public/media
        <Directory /django-pro/site/public/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /django-pro/src/tutorial>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess tutorial python-home=/django-pro/venv python-path=/django-pro/src/
        WSGIProcessGroup tutorial
        WSGIScriptAlias / /django-pro/src/tutorial/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

now even if I revert the changes I made, I cannot access my site as before (I am restarting apache2 service everytime) nor I can access it using https

if possible please tell me my mistakes and how I can also implement ssl for my django project to return 403.

Comment: The server is not reachable on port 443 (https) but only on port 80. This suggest that there is some firewall involved in between or on your server, which need to allow access to port 443. Since there is nothing known about your setup and environment except "apache" no specific instructions can be given of how to configure the firewall(s) involved.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I just remembered that I didn't check the box to allow https when creating Google vm thank you for pointing that out. but I think I messed up a lot.. even if I try it to run on port 80 it doesn't give response.. I will recreate demo from scratch. thank you again for the hint!

Comment: The browser will automatically use https port 443 if you ask for http port 80 since the browser remembers that it has previously seen the permanent redirect you have in your config. You would need to clear all cached data if you want to reach port 80 again with http, or use a different browser profile (like private mode).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I didn't know browsers were saving this redirect too. those are such valuable information thank you so much!!

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it just worked after letting https connection, you are a life saver!!